# How to show/hide fields with ASP.net gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, relational-database

I inherited an *ASP.net* web application that displays data from a *SQL* database using the *ASP.net* `GridView` control.

The problem is that there are more than 20 fields in the table.  It is unlikely that the user would want to see all 20 fields at once, but it is equally implausible that any of the fields could be excluded from the display.

It seems like the solution would be to allow the user to select what fields to show and hide client-side.

Is there a good way to display and hide individual columns of an *ASP.net* `GridView` *client-side*?  If not, what kind of solution should I seek out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript guru so I won't even attempt to answer that part of the question.  But I have had a similar problem to yours, that being too many columns for the screen width you're working with.

I would suggest grouping columns from your DB together into multi-field columns in the GridView using TemplateField.  A lot of many-field data can be visually compressed this way.  I'll give you an example from a lookup tool I designed to work with our ManageEngine ServiceDesk installation:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gridResults" runat="server" BorderColor="#223366" BorderWidth="0px"
            CellPadding="5" DataSourceID="dsResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ResID">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#223366" ForeColor="#F0F0F0" BorderColor="#223366" Font-Bold="true" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" ForeColor="#223366" BorderColor="#223366" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#D0D0D0" ForeColor="#223366" BorderColor="#223366"
                HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Host Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# "<a class=""BlueLink"" href=""https://mgmt-servicedesk.co.wood.wi.us/ViewWSDetails.do?wsId=" & Eval("ResID") & """>" & Eval("ResourceName") & "</a><br/>Serial #: " & Eval("SerialNo") & "<br/>Asset: " & Eval("AssetTag") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# "Status: " & Eval("State") & "<br/>" & Eval("Manufacturer") & "<br/>" & Eval("Model") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Owner/Location">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# "User: " & Eval("UserName") & "<br/>Dept: " & Eval("Department") & "<br/>" & Eval("Location")   %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# RenderDameWareLinks(Eval("ResourceName"))%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No Results
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

When rendered, this is the what the gridview looks like (sorry for so much blurring, can't risk posting our internal records):

[image]

Comment: I considered implementing a solution much like the one you describe, but then I have a new issue: how to allow the user to sort the data by individual fields...

Comment: @Rice: You could provide a `DropDownList` of fields to pick from for sorting at the top, and when the user makes a selection, the page is reloaded and sorted by that column.

Comment: True, and I don't have an example for that offhand.  I would probably try to populate a DropDownList with field names and programatically set the sorting based on that.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a great idea; why didn't I think of that

Answer (score 0):

I have several advanced search pages in my company's intranet site, and I provide checkboxes for every column.  The default's are selected at pageLoad, but the user can change the ones they want before running the search.  Then the sql is generated dynamically in code-behind, and the sqlDataSource is updated.  The grid should be set to automatically generate columns, then your good to go.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see the client-side requirement at first.  Although with an asp.net Update Panel, my solution looks like quick client-side code to the user.  You can even update the grid each time a column is checked or unchecked.

If my solution is of interest, let me know and I can post code examples.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I'm afraid that I may be unwise for me to implement such a solution.  The more senior programmers on my team dislike server-side solutions and the `UpdatePanel` in particular.  I was hoping for a solution to show and hide columns on the fly.

Comment: I believe an asp.net gridview is rendered as an html table.  So you could possibly use html input checkboxes for the user to select the columns, then show/hide the columns from JavaScript.  I've never done that type of operation in JS, however.

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/1264178.aspx/1 for a method to hide gridview columns from JavaScript.